# opensslErrorStack: ERR_OSSL_EVP_UNSUPPORTED

Tags: react-native

I am not able to run the metro server in Windows System.

[image]

I trying to add the following line in package.json file but still not working.

"start": "react-native --openssl-legacy-provider start",
"build": "react-native --openssl-legacy-provider build",

Comment: I Fixed it check Below Solution:-

Replace following in package.json

"start": "set NODE_OPTIONS=--openssl-legacy-provider && react-native start",